# Error: Encountered error during file download: Cannot pipe, not readableCannot pipe, not readable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, render

I recently starting getting this error on my sailsjs project during deploy. Can someone assist in solving this?

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
ERROR Error: Encountered error during file download:  Cannot pipe, not readableCannot pipe, not readable
INFO    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
INFO    at ServerResponse.pipe (node:_http_outgoing:1115:22)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:944:33
INFO    at afterwards (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:971:17)
INFO    at _waitForSimulatedLatencyIfRelevant (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:620:50)
INFO    at Object.respondApropos [as success] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:622:11)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1517:30
INFO    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:1155:14)
INFO    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:913:12)
INFO    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:845:10)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:303:7
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:954:24
INFO    at Function.handlerCbs.success (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:814:26)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1044:42
INFO    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
ERRORerror: Handled a `HEAD` request to  `/`, by running an action, which called its `success` exit.  But then an error occurred: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:944:50
INFO    at afterwards (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:971:17)
INFO    at _waitForSimulatedLatencyIfRelevant (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:620:50)
INFO    at Object.respondApropos [as success] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine-as-action/lib/machine-as-action.js:622:11)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1517:30
INFO    at proceedToFinalAfterExecLC (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:1155:14)
INFO    at proceedToInterceptsAndChecks (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:913:12)
INFO    at proceedToAfterExecSpinlocks (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:845:10)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/parley/lib/private/Deferred.js:303:7
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:954:24
INFO    at Function.handlerCbs.success (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:814:26)
INFO    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:1044:42
INFO    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coh4Z.png)

I have 2 render accounts, one for dev and one for production, same branch connected but i get the error in one. i cant debug why i get the error during deployment. i dont get the error locally too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.